# unable to make hdf5-1.12.0

Tags: 20.04

I'm trying to install hdf5 on ubuntu20.04. I first ran `./configure` and then ran `make`. I am getting this error after running `make` :

```
/usr/bin/sed: can't read Libraries/hdf5-1.12.0/src/libhdf5.la: No such file or directory
libtool:   error: 'Libraries/hdf5-1.12.0/src/libhdf5.la' is not a valid libtool archive
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1683: libfilter_plugin3_dsets.la] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/some name /some name /some name /hdf5-1.12.0/test'
make: *** [Makefile:662: all-recursive] Error 1
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You have to start by getting build-dependencies for [deb-package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/hdf5) by `sudo apt-get build-dep hdf5` .

Comment: Thanks I will try it, but does not ubuntu 20 have hdf5 installed by default?

Comment: @N0rbert running this command gives me this: Reading package lists... Done
E: You must put some 'deb-src URIs in your sources. list